# How to use javascript to click on an element to open a new webpage and close the original popup window？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

At present, I encounter a requirement at work that I don’t know how to implement. I hope that when I click on the notice_item block, it can be closed, the entire notice_dialog block, and a new web page will be opened! Of course, click the show_dialog button at the beginning again to open the notice_dialog block again. But I can't write anything, it's really troublesome ~ The attached picture is the range I want to click (red), and then click to open a new web page in href, and close the green element. I would be very grateful for everyone's help.

```js
const Dialog = $(".notice_dialog");
$(".notice_content").on("click", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest(".notice_dialog")) {
    Dialog.toggle();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  Dialog.hide();
});

// Switch between general tab and order ta
let nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
let buttons = nav.querySelectorAll("button");
let contents = document.querySelectorAll(".notice_content_type");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].setAttribute("data-index", i);
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].className = "";
    }
    //Add the clicked style to yourself
    this.className = "active";
    //Set the dataindex attribute and index numbe
    let index = this.getAttribute("data-index", i);
    for (let i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      contents[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    contents[index].style.display = "block";
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.notice_content {
  position: relative;
}

.notice_content .notice_center {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.notice_content .notice_center .notice_center-num {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 8px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #222;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 346px;
  max-height: 464px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 20px 0px 8px 0px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
  padding: 0px 24px 4px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .head .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .head .all_read {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav button .nav_link {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav button .notice_num {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: 222;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav .active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .nav .active .notice_num {
  color: #222;
  background-color: orange;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type {
  display: none;
  height: 336px;
  background-color: #222;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li {
  text-align: left;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item .info_icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item .info_title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item .info_main {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
}

.notice_content .notice_dialog .notice_content_type li .notice_item .time {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notice_content">
  <button class="notice_center">
    show_dialog
  </button>
  <div class="notice_dialog">
    <div class="head">
      <h2 class="title">notice</h2>
      <button class="all_read">all read</button>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <button class="active">
        <p class="nav_link">generally</p><span class="notice_num">99+</span>
      </button>
      <button>
        <p class="nav_link">orde</p><span class="notice_num">99+</span>
      </button>
    </ul>
    <ul class="notice_content_type" style="display: block">
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item unread" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">GENERALLY TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">GENERALLY TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item unread" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">GENERALLY TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">GENERALLY TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="notice_content_type">
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">ORDER TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">ORDER TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="notice_item" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="notice_content">
            <h3 class="info_title">ORDER TITLE</h3>
            <p class="info_main">CONTENT.....</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think the issue lies within your first click handler:

```
$(".notice_content").on("click", function(e) {    // here you say a click anywhere in the outermost div triggers this handler
  if (!e.target.closest(".notice_dialog")) {      // this is IMHO a strange way to target the button, it would be more precise if you bind that toggle directly to the button
    Dialog.toggle();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();                            // now you are preventing any click on your dialog to bubble up, thus it never reaches the document and therefore never triggers the Dialog.hide()
});
```

So I think it would be clearer if you structure it like this:

```
// click handler for the button (.notice_center) and the item (.notice_item)
// => will close the dialog on click of the button or an item 
$(".notice_center, .notice_item").on("click", function(e) {
  Dialog.toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
// prevent closing the dialog for clicking anywhere in the dialog but the button or an item
$(".notice_content").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I didn't test it, but this should be the solution, because then you're not relying on the click event on the item to bubble up (which it didn't due to the `stopPropagation` call).